# How to add multiple JMS MessageListners in a single MessageListenerContainer for Spring Java Config

Tags: java, xml, spring, jms, spring-jms

I had the following xml code in my spring-config.xml

```
<jms:listener-container acknowledge="auto"
        connection-factory="cachedConnectionFactory" container-type="default"
        error-handler="consumerErrorHandler" concurrency="20-25">
        <jms:listener destination="#{TaskFinished.destination}"
            method="onMessage" ref="taskFinished" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

Now, I was converting my spring xml configuration file to Java configuration.

I translated it like

```
@Bean(name = "consumerJmsListenerContainer")
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer consumerJmsListenerContainer() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    messageListenerContainer
            .setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory());
    messageListenerContainer.setConcurrency("20-25");
    messageListenerContainer.setErrorHandler(new ConsumerErrorHandler());
    messageListenerContainer
            .setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    messageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(new TaskFinished());
    return messageListenerContainer;
}
```

What I need to know is, if there were more than one MessageListner in the Message Container like

```
<jms:listener-container acknowledge="auto"
        connection-factory="cachedConnectionFactory" container-type="default"
        error-handler="consumerErrorHandler" concurrency="20-25">
        <jms:listener destination="#{questionGeneration.destination}"
            method="onMessage" ref="questionGeneration" />
        <jms:listener destination="#{friendShipLogic.destination}"
            method="onMessage" ref="friendShipLogic" />
        <jms:listener destination="#{postAvailabilityChecker.destination}"
            method="onMessage" ref="postAvailabilityChecker" />
        <jms:listener destination="#{playOn.destination}" method="onMessage"
            ref="playOn" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

How could I supposed to convert this xml code into Java config?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The namespace is just a convenience - each `<jms:listener/>` element gets its own `DMLC`; the outer (container) element is just a vehicle to supply common attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `container.setConcurrentConsumers(10);`, where number of consumers is 10

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple annotations, each with its own concurrency.

```java
@JmsListener(id="1", destination = "mydestination", containerFactory = "myfactory", concurrency ="1-5")

@JmsListener(id="2", destination = "mydestination", containerFactory = "myfactory", concurrency = "3-5")
```