# complete jms:listener migration to JavaConfig

Tags: spring, spring-3, spring-jms, spring-4

Like the title says..

I have read this valuable [How to add multiple JMS MessageListners in a single MessageListenerContainer for Spring Java Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881657/how-to-add-multiple-jms-messagelistners-in-a-single-messagelistenercontainer-for) link

The author of that post is working through

```
messageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(new TaskFinished());
```

BTW: I use

```
@Autowired
private ConsumerListener consumerListener;

defaultMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(consumerListener);
```

I am not using the **new** operator.

OK, the restriction of the **setMessageListener** method is: the class must implements the **MessageListener** interface, I have tested and works

My problem is, according with [23.6 JMS Namespace Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jms-namespace)

How represent the following:

```
<jms:listener destination="queue.orders" ref="orderService" method="placeOrder"/>
<jms:listener destination="queue.confirmations" ref="confirmationLogger" method="log"/>
```

through JavaConfig?

They are simple pojo (see the `ref` and `method` attributes)

I want use how an option a simple pojo (@Component or @Service) instead of a **MessageListener** object

In the [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html) API, there is no something to work around this requirement or situation.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<jms:listener destination="queue.orders" ref="orderService" method="placeOrder"/>
```

This xml uses a [`MessageListenerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/adapter/MessageListenerAdapter.html) which you can hand a delegate (the `ref` and a method to execute (default 'handleMessage`).

```
@Configuration
public MyJmsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer consumerJmsListenerContainer() {

        DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        ...
        MessageListenerAdapter listener = new MessageListenerAdapter();
        listener.setDelegate(orderService());
        listener.setDefaultListenerMethod("placeOrder");
        dmlc.setMessageListener(listener);
        return dmlc;
}
```

To use it from Java config use something like the snippet above.

Comment: Thank You Marten, it works!.. I have edited your return variable, must be dmlc, not listener. thank you again