# What is the equivalent of destination-type from jms:listener-container in JavaConfig?

Tags: spring, spring-3, spring-jms, spring-4

What is the equivalent of `destination-type` from `jms:listener-container` in JavaConfig?

I have checked in the API these two following classes without results.

- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html)
- [MessageListenerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/adapter/MessageListenerAdapter.html)

I am trying to create *consumers* for a **topic**, many tutorials in the web use `destination-type="topic"`

According with the [23.6 JMS Namespace Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jms-namespace) section, there is the **Table 23.2. Attributes of the JMS  element** table. Where for the **destination-type** attribute says:

> The JMS destination type for this listener: queue, topic or durableTopic. The default is queue.

For the audience: consider the two following links if you are trying to do a migration from `jms:listener-container` and `jms:listener` for JavaConfig.

- [complete jms:listener migration to JavaConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173809/complete-jmslistener-migration-to-javaconfig)
- [How to add multiple JMS MessageListners in a single MessageListenerContainer for Spring Java Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881657/how-to-add-multiple-jms-messagelistners-in-a-single-messagelistenercontainer-for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, look at the parser (in this case `AbstractListenerContainerParser`); that attribute doesn't map to a single property, it maps to `pubSubDomain` and `subscriptionDurable`...

```
    String destinationType = ele.getAttribute(DESTINATION_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE);
    boolean pubSubDomain = false;
    boolean subscriptionDurable = false;
    if (DESTINATION_TYPE_DURABLE_TOPIC.equals(destinationType)) {
        pubSubDomain = true;
        subscriptionDurable = true;
    }
    else if (DESTINATION_TYPE_TOPIC.equals(destinationType)) {
        pubSubDomain = true;
    }
    else if ("".equals(destinationType) || DESTINATION_TYPE_QUEUE.equals(destinationType)) {
        // the default: queue
    }
    else {
        parserContext.getReaderContext().error("Invalid listener container 'destination-type': " +
                "only \"queue\", \"topic\" and \"durableTopic\" supported.", ele);
    }
    configDef.getPropertyValues().add("pubSubDomain", pubSubDomain);
    configDef.getPropertyValues().add("subscriptionDurable", subscriptionDurable);
```

Comment: I checked the source code of that class in Github - seems it is not the same against this URL: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/config/AbstractListenerContainerParser.java#L229

Comment: Could be improved the Spring Reference documentation about this situation? let me know to create a JIRA issue.

Comment: Yeah, I just happened to have 4.0.3 in my IDE - it was updated recently for the JMS Annotation support: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blame/master/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/config/AbstractListenerContainerParser.java#L229 - feel free to open a documentation improvement JIRA issue.

Answer (score -1):

Though this is a bit late, I would suggest to use the following approach for anyone who is still searching for the answer.

I have created a new Class **DefaultMessageListenerContainerExtended** which extends **DefaultMessageListenerContainer** and I have added one more method as ***setDestinationType***. This does the trick in a nice and familiar way.

Following is the link to source code, which can be found on git:

https://github.com/HVT7/spring-jms-set-destination-type/blob/master/DefaultMessageListenerContainerExtended.java

Also to add, try to use spring version **4.2.5**, as there are minor updates in that version (Had to dig a lot due to version issues as I was using 4.1.5 and Listener Containers did not had function to set "ReplyPubSubDomain" property).